# How do you render a variable as html using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

Using flask, I'm passing in a list of dictionaries to one of the pages. One of the variables contains html text (ex:`var x = <h1>hello</h1>`). How would I get it to display as

## hello

rather than just print out "`<h1>hello</h1>`"? Here's my code so far (post.description has the html variable; It's equal to `<h1>hello</h1>`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <p>{{post.title}}<p>

        {{post.description}}
        
    {% endfor %}
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `safe` to render the HTML code with Jinja.
Example: `{{ post.description | safe }}`